# How to overwrite global policies for a home user account with sudo access?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, user-account, settings

I was trying to overwrite global policies and I found a way to do it, like this:

1. Redirect existing global policies in a new XML file:

   pwpolicy -getaccountpolicies > ~/globalPolicies.xml
2. Edit ~/globalPolicies.xml and remove the first line, "*Getting global account policies*".
3. Modify the rules in globalPolicies.xml and save it as ~/globalPolicies.plist
4. Load it:

   pwpolicy -setaccountpolicies ~/globalPolicies.plist

Even though the above procedure is initially successful, as I can see by checking the policies, when I logout and login back again or restart my computer, the original global policies are restored. The outcome is the same either with sudo or not.

So, what I should do in order for my changes to have a permanent effect?

My computer is a Macbook Pro 2017 with macOS Catalina version 10.15.6.